# Seeding data with Foriegn Keys in a Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have been provided with timezone data which I need to import into my database.

What I do is read in my data, which is in the format:

```
 List<string> items = new List<string>();
            items.Add("AF|Afghanistan|Asia/Kabul|UTC +04:30");
            items.Add("AX|Aland Islands|Europe/Mariehamn|UTC +02:00");
            items.Add("AL|Albania|Europe/Tirane|UTC +01:00");
            items.Add("DZ|Algeria|Africa/Algiers|UTC +01:00");
            items.Add("AS|American Samoa|Pacific/Pago_Pago|UTC -11:00");
            items.Add("AD|Andorra|Europe/Andorra|UTC +01:00");
            items.Add("AO|Angola|Africa/Luanda|UTC +01:00");
            items.Add("AI|Anguilla|America/Anguilla|UTC -04:00");
            items.Add("AQ|Antarctica|Antarctica/Casey|UTC +08:00");
            items.Add("AQ|Antarctica|Antarctica/Davis|UTC +07:00");
            items.Add("AQ|Antarctica|Antarctica/DumontDUrville|UTC +10:00");
            items.Add("AQ|Antarctica|Antarctica/Mawson|UTC +05:00");
            items.Add("AQ|Antarctica|Antarctica/McMurdo|UTC +13:00");
            items.Add("AQ|Antarctica|Antarctica/Palmer|UTC -03:00");
```

So, a Country can have multiple timezones.

I have two entities that this needs to go into:

```
[Table("Country", Schema = "ref")]
public class Country
{
    [Key, Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(2)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }


}
```

and

```
public class Timezone
{
    [Key, Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Country Country { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int GMTOffset { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Country")]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
}
```

What I am doing is going through the list, and adding all the countries.

```
  var timezoneData = data.Timezone.getData();
            //var countries = new List<Country>();
            List<ExistingObject> exists = new List<ExistingObject>();
            int countryId = 1;
            foreach (var item in timezoneData)
            {
                var splitup = item.Split('|');
                if (exists.Any(x => x.Name == splitup[1]))
                {

                    var c = new Country
                    {
                        Code = splitup[0],
                        Description = splitup[1],
                        Id = countryId
                    };

                modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().HasData(new Country[] { c });

                    countryId++;
                    exists.Add(new ExistingObject
                    {
                        Name = splitup[1],
                        Id = countryId,
                    });
                }
            }
```

And then, I need to go and add all the timezones. But, because Timezone has a Country(Id), I am struggling to handle this foreign key relationship in modelBuilder. I was hoping I could just assign the FK value, like this (Note, I am, for now, hard coding CountryID 10, for simplicity)

It would have been nice to just assign the Country object to the timezone.Country, but it's not available yet, it seems. So I am trying to provide the CountryID value that I assigned to the Country object. (Note, hardcoding 10 for now)

```
            foreach (var item in timezoneData)
            {
                int timezoneId = 1;
                var splitup = item.Split('|');
                modelBuilder.Entity<Timezone>().HasData(new Timezone[] { new Timezone
                {
                    Id = timezoneId,
                    CountryId = 10,
                    Description = splitup[2],
                    GMTOffset = 1
                } });

            }
```

However, when I create the migration, it produces the error:

> The seed entity for entity type 'Timezone' cannot be added because another seed entity with the same key value for {'Id'} has already been added. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

It may be easier to create a SQL statement, and execute it, but that seems to move away from migrations. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do, and let the migrations take care of adding my reference data, which has the complexity of a FK?

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with Timezones is one of the most troublesome parts of programming. Generally you try to stay [as far away from manually handling them as you can](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY). "This way lies madness." is no Hyperbole.

When working with timezones in .NET, you have one of the most complete BlackBoxes on your side - Windows.

1. Always store, retrieve and transmit the UTC DateTime. Working the local Timezone in is generally a Display side problem.
2. Never store, retrieve or transmit as Strings
3. If you can not follow rule 2, at least pick a fixed Encoding and Culture format. Existing serialsiation approaches tend to do this part for you.
4. ToString() is capable of working the local timezone in during output. It uses the full ruleset of Windows for this. It will retrieve the user selected timezone for this.
5. All those rules fail if you got a calendar application. But in that case I think DateTime itself might be the wrong tool anyway.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. All my dates are stored as UTC, except transaction dates. If a user selects a date in a date picker (No time, I just deal with dates), I store as the selected date. Because here in Australia, UTC+10, if the user selected 22/Nov/2019, I store it as that. But the server is in UTC, so if I select all transaction 'for today', I'll get yesterdays transaction. I need to know the users timezone, so that I can get for the user's 'today'. Not the server. Your points are highly valid. And I think I'm following them.

Comment: @Craig: Transaction dates are the last thing you should not have in UTC. | Dates without times do no really make sense. The same point in time can be 2, sometimes even 3 different dates - depending on what timezone you are looking at it from. Unless you got a caledar applicationm, you should not try to handle dates and times seperately.